# What purpose does the wax coating on blueberries serve?

Tags: botany

What purpose does the wax coating on blueberries serve? Is it some sort of protective layer?

A [search on the web reveals](http://www.thekitchn.com/whats-that-waxy-coating-on-blueberries-232177) that it is called "bloom". But the source is not a credible, scientific source. And it doesn't explain in detail what the coating does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My uneducated guess is that the wax is called [Epicuticular wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicuticular_wax).

> The main functions of the epicuticular wax are to decrease surface
>   wetting and moisture loss. Other functions include reflection of
>   ultraviolet light, assisting in the formation of an ultrahydrophobic
>   and self-cleaning surface and acting as an anti-climb surface.

Comment: It would seem that your uneducated guess is in fact correct. This kind of cuticular wax is also found on other fruits, such as bananas, grape berries, and (I think) tomatoes.

Answer (score -1):

Years ago my wife and I made  grape juice that turned to wine. This happened because the bloom on the grapes harbors yeast cells. The same situation occurs with other berries including blueberries.  Organisms living on the surface of other organisms are usually symbionts